# Syntax to correctly augment a type from a library

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to replace the defintion of one type in a library which comes with type defintions. I tried various options such as:

```
// untyped.d.ts
declare module "emotion" {
    export const css: (...args: DR<Array<Interpolation>>) => string
}
```

Unfortunatly it doesn't work. Either removes other types of the library, or isn't recognized. What is the proper way to augment a library in a `d.ts` customized file?

Comment: A somewhat tricky aspect of module augmentations is that they need to be defined in a module themselves. I typically add `export {}` at the top of an augmentation file.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, can you elaborate and make it in to an answer, with instructions or code example?

Comment: I can, but can you verify that you don't have some other hidden problem that would invalidate such an answer by adding `export {}` to the top of `untyped.d.ts`?

Comment: @AluanHaddad, here is my current untyped.d.ts. Currently it has no effect. https://gist.github.com/carpben/396e175d056bfdd25e23f1a978c589f6

Comment: It could be that the type declarations in that package are incorrect. Can you provide a link to the emotion package you're using?

Comment: @AluanHaddad,I updated the gist to include full information

Comment: With version 9, the augmentation works perfectly. However, it turns emotion already exports a variable named `css`, leading to an augmentation specific error.

Comment: I think I found the issue try `export {} declare module "emotion/types" {  export const something: ()=>void  }`

Comment: @AluanHaddad, doesn't work. We should bring another option into consideration. DeepReadonlyArray (the generic I wrap the params in) might not work well with type Interpolation. Giving this up, instead will use a wraper function, so I just need to ts-ignore it there.

Comment: Something is wrong with your setup. I am able to augment the module.

Answer (score 3):

you need to import the module before otherwise you replace the complete definition.

```
import "emotion"

declare module "emotion" {
    interface css{
         (...args: DR<Array<Interpolation>>): string
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know that particular library. but what doesn't work for you? you can read here more about declaration merging https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

Comment: It didn't recgnize the new css type.